# connect to chatroom using jabber-net xmpp client library

Tags: .net, xmpp, openfire

I am about to start creating a chat application in .net using xmpp.

To begin with I looked for 2 things. An xmpp server and any kind of .net xmpp client libraries to start building the client.

As far it concerns the server part, I ve selected openfire. So I' ve downloaded it, intalled it and set it to run. Unfortunately with no any client yet to test it.

From the client's part, I ve set my mind to work with jabber-net, but it is quite harse for me because I have not a clue of what I should do here and I think that the documentation is pretty insufficient...

What I am looking for is if someone can give me the proper handle to begin with (not the jabber-net wiki "begin").

Is it possible by just implementing the jabberclient and setting its properties (i.e. NetworkHost, Server, Proxy, User etc) to connect to a chatroom?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Drop the following controls onto a design surface:

1. JabberClient
2. PresenceManager
3. RosterManager
4. ConferenceManager (the [MUC](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) implementation)
5. DiscoManager (find the MUC server)
6. CapsManager (always use [XEP-0115](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html))

They should mostly all hook up to one another automatically.  Register callbacks wherever you like (e.g. `PresenceManager.OnPrimarySessionChange`).  Set whatever properties you want on the JabberClient (perhaps using muzzle.ClientLogin), then call Connect() on JabberClient:

```
muzzle.ClientLogin.Login(jabberClient1, "login.xml");
```

Create a room object, register callbacks, and join the room:

```
Room r = ConferenceManager1.GetRoom("room@server/nick");
r.OnJoin += ... (etc)
r.Join();
```

If you read and understand the [Example](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/trunk/Example/MainForm.cs) application, you should see some of this in action.

Comment: Thanx Joe for your answer. I really hadnt had the time to check it but as soon as I have something I'll let you know!